# Is file path needed in (Shell Function) VBA?

Tags: shell, excel, vba

I have a Matlab-generated executable file, *Myfile.exe* to call from [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba). I learned (Shell Function) is what I need to use.

I don't want to include the whole file path as I do not want to restrict the user to a certain folder in a certain location on each computer.

I have the following code to call the executable, which works fine:

```vb
Sub MyExe()
    On Error Resume Next
    Shell ("C:\Users\elwany\Desktop\Myfolder\Myfile.exe")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Can't start the application.", vbCritical, "Error"
    End If
End Sub
```

**My problem/question is**
I put the executable + the Excel file with the VBA project in the same folder (Myfolder), and then I modify the code to:

```vb
Sub MyExe()
    On Error Resume Next
    Shell ("Myfile.exe")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Can't start the application.", vbCritical, "Error"
    End If
End Sub
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't!

For example, yesterday I ran the VBA code, it worked.  Today I opened the same Excel file, same folder, same everything, it gives "Can't Start Application" error msg!!

1. Is it not okay to remove the file path even if I have everything in one folder?
2. Why does it sometimes work, sometimes not?
3. Is adding the file path absolutely mandatory?

Comment: For future reference you can change the current directory with `ChDir`. so `ChrDir ThisWorkbook.Path` prior to `Shell ("Myfile.exe")` would work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have enquire further about different directories note that you can either

1. Use `ChDir` as per my earlier comment to your question
2. Use `Dir` instead to validate that `myfile.exe` is where it needs to be. This method doesn't need error handling  to handle the file being missing.

   ```
   Sub TestB()
   Dim strPath As String
   strPath = Dir("c:\temp\myfile.exe")
   If Len(strPath) > 0 Then
       Shell strPath
   Else
       MsgBox "Path doesn't exist"
   End If
   End Sub


   Sub TestA()
   On Error Resume Next
   'use the host workbook path
   ' ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path
   'set path here
   ChDir "C:\temp"
   Shell ("Myfile.exe")
   If Err <> 0 Then
       MsgBox "Can't start the application.", vbCritical, "Error"
   Else
       MsgBox "sucess!", vbOKOnly
   End If
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Brettdj, Thanks a lot for your input! really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

When you run a shell like this without a path specified it runs from the Active Directory.  What the Active Directory is depends on the OS, not Excel/VBA (unless you explicitly set it)

Try this instead

```
Sub MyExe()
    On Error Resume Next
    Shell (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Myfile.exe")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Can't start the application.", vbCritical, "Error"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I got your point!  
Your code works.

how do we set the active directory, then?