# How to open matlab by using VBA

Tags: matlab, vba

please help me to solve this problem.

The problem is how to open matlab from VB excel.
I have used code `"matlabinit"`. but when I run it in VB excel, I can open matlab application, but the opened current directory did not like what I want. I want open matlab from VB excel with the specific currect directory as I want.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do it is to call matlab function to [change the current folder](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cd.html). This way it will be specific to your project at hand. So put this line at the start of where you start to interact with matlab:

```
MLEvalString "cd('C:\MyFolder')"
```

Comment: thanks you Mr. Mr.Dan Can you help me to solve my problem in this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965330/how-to-make-faster-looping

Comment: No, that question is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a description of how to do so [here](http://www.mathworks.fr/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/255581).

You use `shell` in VBA to run Matlab, roughly like this:

in VBA

```
shell "C:\Matlab2011a\matlab.exe -r your_function_name
```

and in your Matlab code

```
function yourFunction()
  cd('C:\yourDirectory');  % moves you to your desired directory
                           % your code here
  exit;                    % exits Matlab
end
```

Alternatively you can manage your directory in VB itself by using the method found on this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773678/file-path-in-shell-function-vba)